# Configure kube-scheduler to use only percentage of node's capacity

Tags: kubernetes, kube-scheduler

Is there a way to configure Kube-Scheduler to use only certain percentage of capacity on nodes? For example, I want scheduler to stop scheduling pods on nodes that have 70% of their memory and CPU resources utilized.

Based on the [scheduling policies documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/scheduling/policies/), PodFitsResources predicate seems to fit closest to my requirement. However, is there a way to configure this predicate such that after 70% resources are consumed this node is unavailable during scheduler filtering?

Answer (score 0):

There is way to do that with [setting Kubelet parameters via a config file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/) using `--kube-reserved` flag.

> `kube-reserved` is meant to capture resource reservation for
>   kubernetes system daemons like the `kubelet`, `container runtime`,
>   `node problem detector`, etc.

With setting this flag you will reserve appropriate amount of resources for system (in your use case that would 30%) which will leave with the 70% available resources for your running pods.